# About splitting fields and primitive elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Question 1: Find the splitting field $K$ of $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is the degree of $K/\mathbb{Q}$? ($\textbf{Hint:}$ Recall that $\xi = e^{2\pi i/3}$ is such that $\xi^2 + \xi + 1 = 0$ and $cos(\pi/3) = 1/2$ and $sin(\pi/3) = \sqrt{3}/2)$

Question 2: Find a primitive element $\xi$ for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Prove your claim.

My proof:

Let $x^2 = \xi$, then $\xi^2 + \xi + 1= 0$. Now the roots of this polynomial can be written as
            $$
   \psi_1 = e^{2\pi i/3},\psi_2 = e^{5\pi i/3}
   $$
            Hence,
            $$
   x^2 = e^{2\pi i/3}, \mbox { or } x^2 = e^{5\pi i/3}
   $$
            and
            $$
   x = \pm e^{\pi i/3}, x = \pm e^{5\pi i/6}
   $$
            Therefore, we can write the solutions of the equation as
            $$\begin{align*}
   x_1 =& \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
   x_2 =& - \frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
   x_3 =& -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + i\frac{1}{2} \\
   x_4 =& \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - i\frac{1}{2}
   \end{align*}$$

Now the desired splitting field is $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$. The degree of this extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)/\mathbb{Q}$ can be calculated using this well-known result 
            $$
   [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(i)][\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}] = 2\times2 = 4.
   $$
Alternatively, we can see that 
            $$
   \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i) = \{a1 + b\sqrt{3} + ci + d\sqrt{3}i: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \}
$$
Hence, $\{1,\sqrt{3},{i},\sqrt{3}i\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$ and the degree of this extension is the number of elements in it's basis which is four. $\hspace{5pt}\square$

I just want to know if my solution for question 1 is correct.

About question 2: I know that $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ must be a primitive element but I did not know how to prove it. Maybe the primitive element theorem can help since this extension is finite? Or I have to find some minimal polynomial to prove that $Q(\alpha) = Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$? I was looking in Wikipedia and I found this:

"If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $Q[x]$ is $a(x) = x^4 − 10x^2 + 1 = (x - \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})(x + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3})(x - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})(x + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$.

The minimal polynomial in Q[x] of the sum of the square roots of the first n prime numbers is constructed analogously, and is called a Swinnerton-Dyer polynomial."

This is very interesting for me but in my class they never discuss this theorem.

Any other way to prove this?

Comment: If $x^2 = e^{2 \pi i / 3}$, why's $x = \pm e^{2 \pi i/3}$?

Comment: The two questions seem to have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @xyzzyz it was a typo, since I was lazy and doing copy paste, I should divide both sides by 2 obviously, but the solutions are correct.

Comment: A typo?! I don't think you understand what I meant... Please do not ask several questions in the same post if the questions have nothing to do with each other

Comment: Sorry @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, that was a reply to another user not for you

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez my professor asked those two question together in an old exam, that's why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$. Obviously, we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, so it's enough to prove the opposite inclusion.

Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) \ni (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2 = 2 + 3 + 2 \sqrt{6}$. Therefore, $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$.

Now, $\sqrt{6}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{12} + \sqrt{18} = 2\sqrt{3} + 3 \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$. Therefore, $(2\sqrt{3} + 3 \sqrt{2}) - 2 \cdot (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$, and so also obviously $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$.

Comment: This is very interesting, however I can not see how can I come up with a similar computation if they change the numbers in the exam. What is the reasoning behind ?

Comment: If such computation can be done, it usually can be done by just playing around  with elements, you just need to do various operations and apply the relation given by polynomial defining your elements. Obviously, the lower degree, the less work it is to calculate.

In general, if $a, b$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then for some rational $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(a, b) = \mathbb{Q}(a + rb)$. In fact, this holds for most $r$, so $r = 1$ or $r = -1$ will probably work.